# opening tar file displays "This does not look like a tar archive"

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, tar, archive

I have downloaded some data from the internet and the files come with this format

**file.pth.tar**

when I am trying to open it through **cygwin** terminal it says:

**tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors**

I tried to open it in windows but it says
**Invalid archive open/read error**

I tried to find the file type using: **file full_graph.pth.tar**

and it displays:

**full_graph.pth.tar: data**

Comment: the file is not a TAR file or was corrupted during download

Comment: You could try `od -c full_graph.pth.tar | head` to see if anything recognizable appears.

Comment: @DougHenderson yes it does display some values "0000000 200 002 212  \n   l 374 234   F 371       j 250   P 031   . 200"

Answer (score 0):

I add a similar problem. From the filename, this is a model weight file.

You do not have to extract the file to use it.

For Pytorch, You can simply use it with the following line.

```
weights_path = 'file full_graph.pth.tar'
state_dict = torch.load(weights_path)
```

Comment: This should be after you have confirmed that the downloaded file is valid